# Can't receive information using sockets for some reason

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, sockets

First of all, i'm really new to sockets. If i understand something wrong I'm really sorry.

I want to create a game in windows.forms, using that u can check, who's cps(clicks per second) is higher. Your or youe friends one. I created 2 usercontrols, for game and for menu. it looks like this.
Menu
[menu usercontrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cptoM.png)

Game
[game usercontrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3kdK.png)

I also did this thing for switching user controls.

```
 Game game = new Game();
            game.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.Controls.Add(game);
            Controls.Remove(this);
            game.BringToFront();
```

It works completly fine.

next step was to start the game for host and for guy who is connecting (connecter from now on).

i decided that it's a good idea to just create boolean that is set to true when host gets message "Here!"

Here is the code:

```
 localPort = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            remotePort = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            Game.gameStarted = true;

            iP = IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text);
 try
            {
                sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

                string message = "Here!";

                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                Console.WriteLine(data);
                EndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(iP, remotePort);
                Console.WriteLine(endPoint);
                sock.SendTo(data, endPoint);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Close();
            }

            thread = new Thread(Game.Multiplayer);
            thread.Start();
```

And for getting the message:

```
Menu menu = new Menu();
            while (!gameStarted)
            {
                try
                {
                    IPEndPoint localIp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, Menu.localPort);
                    menu.sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                    menu.sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                    menu.sock.Bind(localIp);

                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting For Players...");
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    int bytes = 0;
                    byte[] data = new byte[256];

                    EndPoint remoteIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 0);
                    do
                    {
                        bytes = menu.sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref remoteIP);
                        builder.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                    }
                    while (menu.sock.Available > 0);

                    if (builder.ToString() == "Here!")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Game Started!");
                        gameStarted = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    Menu.Close();
                }
            }
```

It also works completly fine.

The problem that it's not receiving or sending clicks.

Here is the code for sending clicks (it happens whenever you click button1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Menu menu = new Menu();
            Game game = new Game();
            if (gameStarted)
            {
                yourClicks += 1;
                textBox2.Text = yourClicks.ToString();

                try
                {
                    menu.sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                    menu.sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

                    string message = yourClicks.ToString();
                    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                    EndPoint remotePoint = new IPEndPoint(Menu.iP, Menu.remotePort);
                    menu.sock.SendTo(data, remotePoint);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    Menu.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

And here is for receiving clicks:

```
if (gameStarted == true)
            {
                menu = new Menu();
                game = new Game();

                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        IPEndPoint localIp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, Menu.localPort);
                        menu.sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                        menu.sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                        menu.sock.Bind(localIp);

                        Console.WriteLine("Counting Clicks!");
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        int bytes = 0;
                        byte[] data = new byte[256];

                        EndPoint remoteIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 0);
                        do
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Clicks...");
                            bytes = menu.sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref remoteIP);
                            builder.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                            Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
                        }
                        while (menu.sock.Available > 0);
                        game.textBox1.Text = builder.ToString();
                    }
                    catch (Exception exc)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Menu.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

It all happens in thread that starts whenever you click the "Host" or "Connect" button.

```
            thread = new Thread(Game.Multiplayer);
            thread.Start();
```

I hope you guys help me. I have no idea why it doesn't work, because it receives "Here!" absolutly fine, but doesn't receive clicks at all.

Comment: In your code for sending and recieving clicks, why do you initialize the variables `game` and `menu` every time?

Comment: @Sideways It doesn't work without this. Do you have any idea, why can't i receive info? It looks like it's sending but not receiving. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I mean, if you always create a new instance of your objects, all the data stored in other instances will be gone (at least this is what it looks like). Could you post the entire code including class definitions?

Comment: @Sideways I fixed my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite easy. You just have to close your socket after you get information. I just added socket.Close() after using info i get and everything works fine.